# Update Angular5 form immediately

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form:

```
this.searchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  query: [ null, [Validators.required] ]
});
```

And `onPaste` method where I update my form value, but actually it doesn't update HTML input value until I change the focus out of the input.

```
constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private ref: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) { }

onPaste(event: any): void {
    const pastedQuery = event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');

    const formattedQuery = pastedQuery
      .split(/,?[\r\n\t]+\s?/).join(', ')
      .replace(/,\s?$/g, '');

    this.searchForm.patchValue({
      query: formattedQuery
    });

    this.ref.detectChanges();
  }
```

I call `onPaste` method like this:

```
<input formControlName="query" type="search" (paste)="onPaste($event)">
```

I've found this question [Angular FormGroup won't update it's value immediately after patchValue or setValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44523607/angular-formgroup-wont-update-its-value-immediately-after-patchvalue-or-setval) and trying `detectChanges` but it doesn't help me.

So, where is my mistake, or maybe there is another way to solve my problem?

Comment: Thanks for the update)

Comment: @yurzui `<input formControlName="query" type="search" (paste)="onPaste($event)">`

Comment: I'll try: event.target.dispatchEvent( new Event( "input" ) ) ; but I'm not sure

Comment: or event.target.value=formattedQuery

Comment: Have you tried: `this.searchForm.get('query').setValue(formattedQuery)`?

Comment: @ChauTran it has the same behaviour as `this.searchForm.patchValue({ query: formattedQuery });`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zcbwry I don't know what behavior you're expecting but FormGroup's updating value just fine...

Comment: @ChauTran looks like it updates immediately